# Range of a function involving integration

Tags: integration, functions, inverse-function

Find the range of the function for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$f(\alpha) = \int_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}{\frac{\tan(x)}{\tan(x) + \cot(x)}}dx$$

My attempt: Please verify if my way of solution is correct.

$$f(\alpha) = \int_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}{\frac{\tan(x)}{\tan(x) + \cot(x)}}dx$$
$$\text{or } f(\alpha) = \int_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}{2\sin^2(x)}dx$$
$$\text{or }\, f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}\left({1-\cos(2x)}\right)dx$$
$$\text{or }\, f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\left({x-0.5\sin(2x)}\right)|_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}$$
$$\text{or }\, f(\alpha) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \tan^{-1}{\alpha}$$

So range is $(\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4})$

Comment: Please use \sin , \cos, \tan, \cot, \log for typesetting mathematical functions.

Comment: Note: the range will depend on how you define the range of the inverse cotangent. Wolfram Alpha uses the convention $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\cot^{-1}{\left(x\right)}<\frac{\pi}{2}$, in which case the range of $f$ will be $(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. On the other hand, using the convention $0<\cot^{-1}{\left(x\right)}<\pi$ reproduces the range you found above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$I=\int_a^bf(x)dx =\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

$$I+I=?$$

Comment: For sake of completeness maybe mention the result is derived from substituting $t=a+b-x$

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your first to second step, since you have an excess $2$, since it is  :

$$\frac{\tan(x)}{\tan(x) + \cot(x)} = \sin^2(x)$$

The next identity used is correct. The mistake having the $2$ there makes you have a mistaken $\frac{1}{2}$ as a coefficient in :

$$"\text{or }\, f(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\left({x-0.5\sin(2x)}\right)|_{\tan^{-1}(\alpha)}^{\cot^{-1}(\alpha)}"$$

Also, as a tip, please use \sin, \cos, \tan, \cot etc between dollars for coding and typesetting mathematical functions in $LaTeX$.